# Laravel subdomains route and controller parametrs

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I have question.
My routes is

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.'.$domain], function () {
    Route::get('/confirmmail/{hash}', 'Auth\RegisterController@confirmEmail');
});
```

And my controller method is

```
public function confirmEmail($domain, $hash)
{
    $user = User::where('confirm_token', $hash)->firstOrFail();
    $affectedRows = $user->update(array('active' => 1));
    if ($affectedRows) {
        Auth::login($user);
        return Redirect::to('http://'.$user->workshop->slug.'.'.config('app.domain'));
    } else {
        echo "nie";
    }

}
```

In my method I must use two parametrs $domain and $hash, how I must change route to have

```
function confirmEmail($hash)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the route parameters from the request helper

```
request()->route('domain')

request()->route('hash')
```